# Найти промежуток времени от одной отметки до другой. Python

Tags: python, дата, время

С клавиатуры надо ввести две отметки времени в формате (hh:mm:ss). Необходимо посчитать сколько времени (в формате hh:mm:ss) прошло от одной отметки до другой.
Как можно реализовать данную задачу?

Comment: сесть и написать код, например. на питоне, например. вообще, с такими вопросами - не сюда. сюда - с проблемами в _вашем решении_ .

Answer (score 1):

Через библиотеку datetime.

```
from datetime import datetime

time_0 = input("First: ")
time_1 = input("Second: ")
format = "%H:%M:%S"
td = datetime.strptime(time_1, format) - datetime.strptime(time_0, format)
print(td)
```

Пример работы

First: 00:10:20

Second: 01:20:25

1:10:05